# Count the number of cells in a column contain a particular value in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, count

I want to identify and count uris that contain the following values

```
ukpga
ukla
asp
asc
anaw
mwa
ukcm
nia
aosp
aep
aip
apgb
nisi
mnia
apni
```

I have a column in the table that has a list of uris.

The query below is what I have done so far - this works but it will become a very long query so I wanted to find a way to shorten it.

```
SELECT 'uksi' AS legtype,
 COUNT (uri)  
FROM "default"."www-live-lon-cf" 
WHERE date >= date('2023-02-01')
  AND date <= date('2023-08-31')
  AND uri LIKE '%.uksi'
UNION
SELECT 'ukpga' AS legtype,
 COUNT (uri)  
FROM "default"."www-live-lon-cf" 
WHERE date >= date('2023-02-01')
  AND date <= date('2023-08-31')
  AND uri LIKE '%.ukpga'
```

Comment: You can use INSTR function in mysql. SELECT INSTR('foobarbar', 'bar'); INSTR will give 4 in this case.  It is good to know string functions. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr

Comment: Also you can use CASE INSTR('foobarbar', uksi) > -1 THEN uksi as legtype

Comment: Any chance you could post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE (tbl_name): so we can see your available column names and attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a column for your legtype values and then count grouping by those :

```
WITH regrouped_uri AS(

SELECT CASE
            WHEN uri LIKE '%.ukpga' THEN 'ukpga'
            WHEN uri LIKE '%.uksi' THEN 'uksi'
            ELSE null
        END AS legtype,
        uri
FROM "default"."www-live-lon-cf"

WHERE date >= date('2023-02-01') 
  AND date <= date('2023-08-31')
)

SELECT legtype,
        COUNT(uri) AS count_uri
FROM regrouped_uri
GROUP BY legtype
```

You just need to adapt the case to create legtype with your other values.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a procedure if you have to do the same query for a lot of uris.

To create a procedure I suggest you to follow this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html)

**EDIT:**

In your case you can do as followed :

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE uriCounter (IN uriCode CHAR(50), OUT uris INT)
       BEGIN
         SELECT COUNT(*) INTO uris FROM "default"."www-live-lon-cf" 
         WHERE uri = uriCode;
       END//

delimiter ;
```

Then you only need to call the uriCounter procedure and the select for each uris as followed :

```
CALL uriCounter('%.ukpga', @uris);

SELECT @uris;
```

Comment: I would suggest adding this as a comment rather than answer.

Comment: @Isolated As I only have 21 of reputation I cannot comment on the question

Comment: @ThomasLiné that is no reeason to abuse the answer system for comments. Just focus on answering questions that don't need elaboration to gather the 50 rep needed to place comments.

Comment: @MarkBaijens I am just trying to help, but thanks for the feedback I will wait to have enough reputation

Answer (score 0):

This approach create a temporary in memory table for the legtypes:

```sql
WITH lt (legtype) AS (
    VALUES
        ROW('uksi'), ROW('ukpga'), ROW('ukla'), ROW('asp'),
        ROW('asc'), ROW('anaw'), ROW('mwa'), ROW('ukcm'),
        ROW('nia'), ROW('aosp'), ROW('aep'), ROW('aip'),
        ROW('apgb'), ROW('nisi'), ROW('mnia'), ROW('apni')
)
SELECT lt.legtype, COUNT(cf.uri)
FROM lt
LEFT JOIN `www-live-lon-cf` cf
    ON lt.legtype = SUBSTRING_INDEX(cf.uri, '.', -1)
    AND cf.date >= '2023-02-01'
    AND cf.date <= '2023-08-31'
GROUP BY lt.legtype;
```

Note: The [`VALUES Statement`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html) was introduced in MySQL 8.0.19.

With my test dataset (~1M rows with ~300k within date range) this query takes slightly longer (~0.78s vs 0.81s) than [Aurélien.AB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77273594).

---

This is a really simple query, but whether it is a viable option depends on the distribution of your data. Because it works by splitting off everything after the last `.` in `uri`, it may produce a lot more rows than the other approaches.

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(uri, '.', -1) AS legtype, COUNT(*)
FROM `www-live-lon-cf`
WHERE date >= '2023-02-01'
  AND date <= '2023-08-31'
GROUP BY legtype;
```

With the same test dataset this query is much faster at ~0.49s.